# Replacements for com.lowagie.text.Cell, com.lowagie.text.Table and com.lowagie.text.HeaderFooter

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to upgrade from the old com.lowagie.itext to jars but can't find these classes in the new jar. I know these have been removed from the new jar but would like to know what is the replacement for these? How do I get my code working again without too much refactoring?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you are using `Cell` and `Table`, it will probably be easier for you to upgrade to iText 7 instead of to iText 5. There are plenty of iText 7 `Table` and `Cell` examples in the official documentation. See http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give it a shot.